# Why I m getting Heap Overflow Runtime Error, when my output is correct?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sum, runtime

Leetcode Problem:https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

**My solution for this question is giving a heap overflow error for vectors of sizes of power of 2..i.e 4,8,16  etc. while it is completely working fine for rest of the test cases. Couldn't figure the bug why so is happening!**

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
         vector<vector<int> > v;
        int n=nums.size();
        if(n<3)
            return {};
        
        sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());

for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
    if(i>0 and nums[i]==nums[i-1])
        continue;

        int left = i + 1;
        int right = n - 1;
        while (left <right)
        {   
            int  sum = nums[left] + nums[right]+nums[i];
            if (sum ==0)
            {
            v.push_back({nums[i],nums[left],nums[right]}); 
                
            while(nums[left]==nums[left+1] and left<right)
            left++;
                
            while(nums[right]==nums[right-1] and left<right)
            right--;
                
            left++;
            right--;    
            }
            else if (sum < 0 )
                {
                    left++;
                }
                else
                {
                    right--;
                }
     }   
     }
    return v;      
    }
                        
};
```

Comment: `while(nums[left]==nums[left+1] and left<right) left++;` -> `while(left<right and nums[left]==nums[left+1]) left++;`?

Comment: Thanks@Jarod. I tried this and it worked. but m still couldn't figure out why did it give a runtime error before? The loop would anyway stop if any of the two conditions dont follow, and so when left>=right ..the whole inner while loop inside "for" would stop..so why a heap overflow?? Can you help in this..

Comment: `nums[left+1]` can be out of bound if you don't check bound first.